# How to generate a random number in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, random

I wanted to write a function generate some numbers which represent

> 2 = White,
>     3 = Red,
>      4 = Green,
>     5 = Blue,
>      6 = Yellow

I know that if it is equal probability, then I can write

> GenerateColor = Int(Rnd() * 5) + 2

However, I want to generate white half of the time and share the other half with the remaining 4 colors, how can I do? (It means 50% probability is white, 50% of probability is remaining 4 colors.)

Comment: Do it twice...First 50/50 to see if WHITE or RANDOM, then use RND again to choose the other 4 colors

Comment: Generate 2 instead. First one will be random between a 0 and a 1, and if it's 0, use white, and if it's 1, generate one for 3 to 6.

Comment: Or you can use `GenerateColor = Application.Max(2, Int(Rnd() * 8) - 1)` (But doing it in two steps as per the other comments will be more understandable.)  (Reposted the comment because I think the brackets were wrong first time.)

Comment: If you want to use another distribution types, different from Uniform, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14591417/7690982). But i think that your case uses Bernoulli or Uniform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also do this without VBA:

```
=IF(RAND()<0.5,2,FLOOR(RAND()*4,1)+3)
```

This gives a 50% chance to return 2, and the other 50% is evenly distributed between 3 and 6.

Answer (score 7):

Give this a try:

```
Sub RanGen()
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        x = .RandBetween(1, 2)
        If x = 2 Then
            MsgBox x
        Else
            x = .RandBetween(3, 6)
            MsgBox x
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

In a worksheet formula this would be similar to,

```
=choose(randbetween(1, 2), "white", choose(randbetween(1, 4), "red", "green", "blue", "yellow"))
```

You can code that in VBA using native VBA functions or simply add `worksheetfunction` in several places.

Comment: That would actually be simpler if you just wrote `=choose(randbetween(1, 8), "white", "white", "white", "white", "red", "green", "blue", "yellow")`

Comment: Yes, I had been thinking about stacking up the *white* to get the correct ratio but I tend to avoid repetitious (i.e. *ugly*) code like that.

Comment: er... uh... non-elegant...?

Comment: I'll make it "pretty" by suggesting `=choose(Max(1,randbetween(-2, 5)), "white", "red", "green", "blue", "yellow")`

Comment: (But, as I said in my comment on the question itself, the two step approach you used will be more understandable.)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a helper column with cumulative values like this:

[image]

The formula you use for result is:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$6,COUNTIF($D$2:$D$6,"<="&RAND())+1)
```

The formula in `column D` just a simple `SUM` function:

`=SUM($C$2:C2)`

This should also give you the result you are looking for and will be easier to change in the future.